# Jquery Flot - Detect Point Clicked On Graph

Tags: jquery, flot

I have just today begun trying out the various feature available in the JQuery graphing plugin named Flot. I seem to be getting an error when attempting to identify which point I have clicked. This fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/devin85/BxjgV/) contains my initial attempt at combining a bubble graph with a standard line graph. The method below is where ew detect the click, however it always seems to identify point 11 in the series.

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
            console.log(item)
            if (item) {
                $("#clickdata").text("You clicked point " + item.dataIndex + " in " + item.series.label + ".");
                plot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
            }
        });
```

Can someone please show me why the point clicked is always the final point in the series?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It appears to be a bug in the bubble plugin; if you disable bubbles then all the interaction works correctly.  It may be worth contacting Juergen Marsch, the plugin's author, to see whether he's aware of the problem.

Comment: In some conditions it could work: http://jsfiddle.net/BxjgV/4/

Comment: Is the only time the bug doesnt occur when the series do not converge?

Comment: I made contact with the creator and he has explained that the bugs are sorted and the latest versions available at http://jumflot.jumware.com/

Answer (score 0):

The problem encountered was due to the plugin versioning. I made contact with the Author and the latest versions with the above bugs fixed can be found on his site at: http://jumflot.jumware.com/